# Remove /r /n tags from TinyMCE data in MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, tinymce

When retrieving content stored in the database and displaying it on the screen, my output has /r/n tags.  I've been able to strip away the slashes as a side effect from removing other tags by using:

```
htmlspecialchars_decode(stripslashes($row[Content]))
```

However, the 'rn' character still remain in the output.  I still want it to be a line break but I can't figure out how to do it in my external tinymce javascript file.  Any help would be appreciated!  (I am using html, php, and js)

Comment: Presumably you mean `\r\n` ... and they're not tags merely notation for Carriage Return, Line Feed (aka `CRLF` - e.g. Windows line terminator) - they shouldn't be in your database literally as `\r\n` anyway; you're doing something squiffy somewhere else... otherwise you could look at `nl2br` : http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Answer (score -1):

not sure if this exactly what you want but if you add this code:

tinyMCE.init({
        ...
        remove_linebreaks : false
});

and changed false to true and that might work for you.

Link below for more info.

http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x:remove_linebreaks